# Making a child div move a parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is a follow-up to a question I asked yesterday that I have since been unable to solve.

I am trying to figure out how to imitate a dual push-menu layout from this website: https://www.etq-amsterdam.com/

The buttons on either side of the website's header open a menu from the left or right hand side.

I have made an attempt to achieve this in a jsfiddle which I'll include below. In this fiddle, I have applied the same `transform:translate3d` rules to the push-menus as in the website link above. What I can't figure out is how they've managed to get the `body` of the site to move left or right alongside the menus, thus creating the "push" effect. If I add `transform:translate3d directly to the`body` of my example, it breaks the fixed positioning on the header.

As somebody pointed out to me yesterday, the website above uses a child div of the `body` to which the `transform:translate3d` styles are applied, but what I'm finding impossible to work out is how they have managed to get the child div to move not only the `body`, but all the other child divs as well, i.e the header, footer etc. Surely if a div is subordinate to another, any CSS applied to it shouldn't be able to move the parents too?

**Here is the HTML structure of the website above according to inspect element**

```
<body class=“is-desktop has-header-background is-loading”>
    <div class=“header”></div>
    <aside  id=“sidemenu”> class=“sidemenu”>…</aside>
    <aside  id=“shoppingcart”> class=“shoppingcart” data-quantity=“0”>…</aside>
    <main id=“js-page-view” class=“page-view app-started”>
        <div class=“page home-page” style=“opacity: 1;”> ==$0
            <div class=“transform-container”>…</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The div that has the `transform:translate3d` styles applied to it is the one with the class – `"transform-container"`.

From the look of the structure, it seems as though this div is a "great-grandchild" of the `body` and yet it seems able to move the `body` and all the other divs that are above it in the structure. How is this possible?

Here is my example in a jsfiddle. I have managed to make the menus move on both sides in the same way as the website I've linked, but as mentioned, I can't get the body to move without breaking the fixed positioning on the header.

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what these guys are doing is, moving the id="navBar" & the content, whatever the id or class for that is.

Because they're doing it on a child element not the header element it will work.

Unfortunately because you are missing extra markup in your code & or keeping elements inside of the header you'll have a hard time doing it.

So you can see here:

```
.header .nav {
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1);
}

.open-left .header .nav {
  transform: translate3d(281px,0,0);
}
```

New header markup:

```
 <header class="header">
  <div class="nav">
  <span id="button-one"></span>
  <span id="button-two"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="push-menu-one"></div>
  <div class="push-menu-two"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
```

You can see this working in the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/12/

Comment: Thanks Andy, I never thought I'd find an answer to that one. So am I understanding correctly that if a parent has `position:fixed`, and the child div gets the `transform` CSS, it won't break the fixed positioning of the parent? Another thing I noticed is that the content div seems to have travelled up the `z-index` since the `transform` rule has been applied – is there a way to combat this?

Comment: Pretty much spot on there, transforming the header relates to all its child elements following suit - and for some reason turning into a weird overflow hidden situation. Yes not sure why that is happening i guess just stick a high z-index on the overlay and sidebars. Happy to have helped.